# Can a smart contract automatically send message to an user address in ethereum blockchain

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm a new beginner in the ethereum Blockchain.

I want to implement a smart contract that verifies the authenticity of a user and then send a message to a cloud service (with is the smart contract creator) in case of positive verification to grant access to the user.
My question is it possible for a smart contract to return results of his methods invocation to another blockchain user and how we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

A smart contract cannot make calls outside of the blockchain. i.e., you cannot have it call an http endpoint or something similar.

In ethereum, the usual way of achieving something like this is:

1. Have the user make a transaction passing relevant data to your smart contract
2. The smart contract runs whatever verification logic it must on that data
3. The smart contract logs an [Event](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html?#events)
4. You have an ethereum node that your code connects to and listens for these events.